# The virtual path ** maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net

Is this possible:

I have web application with usercontrols in the following directory : 
C:\Users\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MS\Controls

I have another web application on my machine with the following location : 
C:\Users\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestSite

Can TestSite load the userwebcontrol from different directory.

I tried the following in TestSite:

```
myUserControl = (UserControl)LoadControl("../WebSites/CMS/Controls/test.ascx");
```

But i get the error: The virtual path '/WebSites/MS/Controls/test.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Tried using  ~ at the beginning but comes up with The file '/TestSite/MS/Controls/Editor.ascx' does not exist.

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in the same situation.
Did this ever get resolved?

Comment: Same here, trying to load a usercontrol from another console app, which doesn't have the context of virtual path, how could we load that user control then?! any ideas?

Comment: Also would like an update if you did get this resolved.

Answer (score 5):

[UserControl.LoadControls(path) uses a VIRTUAL PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx), not a file-system path. If your VisualStudio project's root is C:\Users\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestSite, then that is as low as that application will be able to reference (using the '~').

Comment: My project virtual path needed to be setup properly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a wrong value for `Layout` in the cshtml file.
It should be

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MySiteMaster.cshtml"
```

instead of

```
Layout = "/Views/Shared/_MySiteMaster.cshtml"
```